# Sql logshipping Last_restored,last_copied file null in sysjobhistory

Tags: log-shipping

I have started log shipping for few dbs from production to DR recently, but it seems like the jobs just keep running and sometimes the copy job copies few files, sometimes it says the files already exists, the restore job sometimes says skipping backup files and sometimes restores the files , i feel it has something to do with "last_restored_file from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary " being NULL, i am not sure why its not being populated by the monitor server.

Any ideas?

Comment: is logshipping working fine ? may be its broken due to log file missing ?

Comment: No i have checked its not erroring out,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally, The logshipping linked server between monitor and Secondary server was not working, Opened up rules on firewall to let them communicate. Started working